# Append dataframes while ignoring column names

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have a loop which produces a dataframe at every iteration.

```
DimensionAll=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    ###code here###
    DimensionAll.append(MatrixDimension)
```

where `MatrixDimension` is as follows:

```
       Cameroun    Rwanda     Niger    Zambia      Mali    Angola  Ethiopia  
 ECON  0.092811  0.088966  0.077843  0.101176  0.080969  0.045516  0.084101   
 FOOD  0.052086  0.035915  0.037474  0.025168  0.039382  0.015079  0.083499   
 ENV   0.018479  0.043677  0.004737  0.003744  0.009258  0.034044  0.010285   
 HEA   0.000061  0.029189  0.012335  0.001238  0.019010  0.007995  0.017359   
 PERS  0.056941  0.005222  0.048715  0.030879  0.070985  0.064726  0.023330   
 COM   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.009809  0.005251  0.099614   
 POL   0.025177  0.090846  0.005273  0.029481  0.001929  0.065365  0.034342
```

How can I ignore the column names when appending? is there a different way to append or concatenate the dataframes after each iteration (while keeping the column names at top without repetition)?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code gave me the answer i was looking for :

```
DimensionAll=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    ###code here###
    DimensionAll.append(MatrixDimension)
DimensionAll= pd.concat(DimensionAll)
```